# How to write browser flags in SCSS / COMPASS?

Tags: css, browser, compass-sass, flags, sass

Maybe I am totally not understanding something but I don't understand how to write browser flags in SCSS with COMPASS. I know Compass handles a lot of css3 stuff but I need to write a lot of webkit or ms code for example in plain CSS:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
::-moz-selection { }
```

How do I write these?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if they don't need to be repeated a lot, just write them.

Or create you own mixins:

```
@mixin highlight($color: rgba(0,0,0,0)) {
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: $color
}
```

Comment: oh okay. My editor was highlighting them as if they were written incorrectly which led me to believe that although they will render fine, there is a cleaner way to write them.